# IndexError: list index out of range on first line of loop

Tags: list, indexing, indexoutofrangeexception

I keep getting an "IndexError: list index out of range" error on the first line of the body of my loop and I don't know why.  The first line should be the minimum of the first combination, each player in the combination, and his average score on the first hole.  I can print out each number using list(comb)[0][0][0] format, so I don't know why I would get this error on the first line of my loop.  Would love some help. Thanks!

```
from itertools import combinations

stenson = ['stenson', 3.5, 3.5, 4.5, 3.5, 5, 4, 3.5, 4, 4, 4.5, 3.5, 4, 3.5, 5, 4, 3.5, 2.5, 4.5]
deChambeau = ['deChambeau', 4, 3.5, 4.5, 3.5, 4, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 4.5, 4, 4, 4.5, 4, 4.5, 4, 4.5, 3, 4]
burns = ['burns', 4, 3.5, 5.5, 4, 5, 4.5, 4, 4.5, 3.5, 4, 3, 5.5, 4, 3.5, 4.5, 4.5, 2.5, 3.5]
johnson = ['johnson', 4.5, 3, 4, 3, 4.5, 4.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4, 4, 2, 4.5, 4, 4.5, 4, 4.5, 3, 4]
finau = ['finau', 4.5, 3.5, 4.5, 3.5, 5, 5, 3.5, 3.5, 5, 4.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 5, 4.5, 4, 3, 4]
fowler = ['fowler', 4, 3.5, 3.5, 4, 5, 4.5, 2.5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 3, 4.5]
leishman = ['leishman', 4, 3, 4.5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4.5, 4.5, 3, 4, 4, 4.5, 4, 4.5, 3, 4]
matsuyama = ['matsuyama', 4.5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3.5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3.5, 3.5, 4.5, 4, 4.5, 6, 3, 3.5]
mickelson = ['mickelson', 4.5, 3.5, 5, 4, 4, 4.5, 3, 4.5, 4, 4, 3, 4.5, 4.5, 4, 3.5, 5.5, 3, 4]
reed = ['reed', 4, 4, 4.5, 4, 4.5, 4.5, 3, 4.5, 4, 3.5, 2.5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 3.5]


players_scorecards = []
players_scorecards.append(stenson)
players_scorecards.append(deChambeau)
players_scorecards.append(burns)
players_scorecards.append(johnson)
players_scorecards.append(finau)
players_scorecards.append(fowler)
players_scorecards.append(leishman)
players_scorecards.append(matsuyama)
players_scorecards.append(mickelson)
players_scorecards.append(reed)


comb = combinations([players_scorecards[0], players_scorecards[1], players_scorecards[2], players_scorecards[3], players_scorecards[4], players_scorecards[5], players_scorecards[6], players_scorecards[7], players_scorecards[8], players_scorecards[9]], 4)

team = []
lowSum = 0
i = 0
while i < len(list(comb)):
    min1 = min(list(comb)[i][0][1], list(comb)[i][1][1], list(comb)[i][2][1], list(comb)[i][3][1])
    min2 = min(list(comb)[i][0][2], list(comb)[i][1][2], list(comb)[i][2][2], list(comb)[i][3][2])
    min3 = min(list(comb)[i][0][3], list(comb)[i][1][3], list(comb)[i][2][3], list(comb)[i][3][3])
    min4 = min(list(comb)[i][0][4], list(comb)[i][1][4], list(comb)[i][2][4], list(comb)[i][3][4])
    min5 = min(list(comb)[i][0][5], list(comb)[i][1][5], list(comb)[i][2][5], list(comb)[i][3][5])
    min6 = min(list(comb)[i][0][6], list(comb)[i][1][6], list(comb)[i][2][6], list(comb)[i][3][6])
    min7 = min(list(comb)[i][0][7], list(comb)[i][1][7], list(comb)[i][2][7], list(comb)[i][3][7])
    min8 = min(list(comb)[i][0][8], list(comb)[i][1][8], list(comb)[i][2][8], list(comb)[i][3][8])
    min9 = min(list(comb)[i][0][9], list(comb)[i][1][9], list(comb)[i][2][9], list(comb)[i][3][9])
    min10 = min(list(comb)[i][0][10], list(comb)[i][1][10], list(comb)[i][2][10], list(comb)[i][3][10])
    min11 = min(list(comb)[i][0][11], list(comb)[i][1][11], list(comb)[i][2][11], list(comb)[i][3][11])
    min12 = min(list(comb)[i][0][12], list(comb)[i][1][12], list(comb)[i][2][12], list(comb)[i][3][12])
    min13 = min(list(comb)[i][0][13], list(comb)[i][1][13], list(comb)[i][2][13], list(comb)[i][3][13])
    min14 = min(list(comb)[i][0][14], list(comb)[i][1][14], list(comb)[i][2][14], list(comb)[i][3][14])
    min15 = min(list(comb)[i][0][15], list(comb)[i][1][15], list(comb)[i][2][15], list(comb)[i][3][15])
    min16 = min(list(comb)[i][0][16], list(comb)[i][1][16], list(comb)[i][2][16], list(comb)[i][3][16])
    min17 = min(list(comb)[i][0][17], list(comb)[i][1][17], list(comb)[i][2][17], list(comb)[i][3][17])
    min18 = min(list(comb)[i][0][18], list(comb)[i][1][18], list(comb)[i][2][18], list(comb)[i][3][18])
    sum = min1 + min2 + min3 + min4 + min5 + min6 + min7 + min8 + min9 + min10 + min11 + min12 + min13 + min14 + min15 + min16 + min17 + min18
    if lowSum > sum:
        lowSum = sum
        team[0] = list(comb)[i]
    i += 1

print(team)
```

Comment: You sure there you can access list(comb)[0][3][1])?

Comment: Yeah, I can print list(comb)[0][3][1] and get the number I'm looking for.  So I'm not sure why I can't access it in the loop.